# Error while trying to copy a file from a container to my local mac

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to copy a file from a container to my mac and I also look into this question [How to copy files from kubernetes Pods to local system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407277/how-to-copy-files-from-kubernetes-pods-to-local-system) but didn’t help

at first, I tried

```
kubectl cp -n company -c company-web-falcon company/company-web-falcon-bb86d79cf-6jcqq:/etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem /etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem
```

which resulted in this error

```
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
```

So I tried this

```
kubectl cp -n company -c company-web-falcon company/company-web-falcon-bb86d79cf-6jcqq:/etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem /etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem  .
```

which resulted in this error

```
    error: source and destination are required
```

how should I fix it?

Comment: remove the `slash` from the pod path i.e `/etc` it should be `etc/..` and it should work `kubectl cp -n company -c company-web-falcon company/company-web-falcon-bb86d79cf-6jcqq:etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem /etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem`

Comment: @Adiii its failing on the file name tar: etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: then seems like `Workingdir` is set either in the docker image or deployment, so other way would be `kubectl exec company-web-falcon -- bash "cp -r /etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem .` then run the `cp` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the file with the following command [kubectl cp](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp)

- Copy /tmp/foo_dir local directory to /tmp/bar_dir in a remote pod in the default namespace

```bash
kubectl cp /tmp/foo_dir <some-pod>:/tmp/bar_dir
```

- Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in a specific container

```bash
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-pod>:/tmp/bar -c <specific-container>
```

- Copy /tmp/foo local file to /tmp/bar in a remote pod in namespace

```bash
kubectl cp /tmp/foo <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/bar
```

- Copy /tmp/foo from a remote pod to /tmp/bar locally

```bash
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:/tmp/foo /tmp/bar
```

As for the warning that you receive, you can get more details in the github [issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58692)
There are multiple accepted explanations. The best one is the following

You move the wanted file to the working dir in the pod (the directory which is automatically opened, when you open bash on it) -

```bash
user@podname:/usr/src# ls data.txt
data.txt
```

In this case it is - /usr/src folder.

Then in the local bash terminal -

```bash
user@local:~$ kubectl cp podname:data.txt data.txt
user@local:~$ ls data.txt
data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

So based on the comment seems like `WORKINGDIR` is set either in the docker file or in the deployment, in that case, [it will fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60224580/how-to-overrwite-directory-using-kubectl-cp). so if you want to achieve this you should move it to the working directory.

```
kubectl exec company-web-falcon-bb86d79cf-6jcqq -c company-web-falcon -- bash -c "cp /etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem ." && kubectl cp -n company -c company-web-falcon company/company-web-falcon-bb86d79cf-6jcqq:security-ca.pem /etc/identity/ca/security-ca.pem
```

Comment: my workdir is empty and read only - if i have a workdir i can only copy files from work dir ?

Comment: i do not think its empty, having same issue on mac in the past, you can check the above, `cp file .` will copy it to working dir and then you will see that the copy command work. but the cp command looking into `working` directory